# Regex replace specified text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I want to replace some words in text, but only on conditions as, for example, if each is surrounded by whitespace.

To do this, I use:

```
Regex rx = Regex(@"\s+" + word + @"\s+");
str = rx.Replace(str, word2);
```

In the end, I get spaces replaced as well (and all the other specified surroundings). How can this be bypassed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `\b` anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) to match the boundary between a `\w` (alphanumeric) and a `\W` (non-alphanumeric) character.:

```
Debug.Assert(Regex.Match(word, "^\w+$").Success);

string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b" + word + @"\b", word2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = Regex.Replace(str ,@"(?<first>\s+)" + word + @"(?<last>\s+)","${first}" + word2 + "${last}");
```

Comment: Interesting example, thought of something similar, but wasn't aware of this way to access group value. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression looks ok to me for the pattern you describe.  I use [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to help verify my regular expression patterns. There is also [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), an online tool